# SLURM, using srun to print outputs

Tags: slurm

I am using `srun` to run my program, however, it cannot print the output.

```
me@home:~$ srun -p K80q --gres=gpu:1 -N 1 python3 main.py 
2019-05-15 19:56:43.305156: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-05-15 19:56:43.543516: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1392] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:85:00.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.10GiB
2019-05-15 19:56:43.543567: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1471] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-05-15 19:56:43.900189: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:952] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-05-15 19:56:43.900248: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:958]      0 
2019-05-15 19:56:43.900257: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   N 
2019-05-15 19:56:43.900619: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1084] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10761 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:85:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
```

I only got the above output and it cannot print the information I expected. How can I fix it?

By the way, simply define a test code

```py
import tensorflow 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        print('Hello')
```

It can print `Hello` 10 times.

**Update:**

After 20 minutes, it outputs some information I expected. How can I make it output immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `-u` option of `srun`:

> -u, --unbuffered
>                 By  default  the  connection between slurmstepd and the user launched application is over a pipe. The stdio output written by
>   the application is
>                 buffered by the glibc until it is flushed or the output is set as unbuffered.  See setbuf(3). If this option is specified the
>   tasks are executed
>                 with a pseudo terminal so that the application output is unbuffered.